# A way to create random-noise background image (png) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, png, background-image, client-side

The new layout of YouTube added a background random-noise which I like very much, having seen almost exactely the same effect on other sites, so I plan to use the same technique in my webpage prototypes, or at least have this "trick" in my toolbox for future use.

The image is like this (taken from http://g.raphaeljs.com/barchart.html):

[image]

Now Youtube accomplishes the (embarrassingly identical) same effect by embedding the image in source code:

(on Youtube main page, right click background to display it, then right click the image and "display image properties" [ffox]):

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJUAAACVCAAAAAB0....lotsofdata
```

I tried to discover where this line of code is in the source code, but due to the dynamic creation, I couldn't.

So, my question is:
"Is there a way to apply a tiled background to a page, using a png image generated algorithmically CLIENT-SIDE?" (preferrably with javascript)

I am very beginner in webdev and javascript, but I like to base my learning around defined problems to be solved, so this would be a nice way to learn something

Thanks for reading!

UPDATE:

For anyone interested in tile texture generation using javascript, I found this, which seems very interesting:

http://somethinghitme.com/projects/canvasterrain/

http://somethinghitme.com/projects/canvasterrain/js/canvasTerrain.js

Comment: Hmm, you have to look very closely, but the image is indeed *not* a solid gray color.

Comment: Yeah, put it on a tiling pattern, and you end up with something that seems "paperish" natural texture. I wonder if the same effect could be obtained with a much smaller-sized square.

Comment: algorithmically generating the image seems like overkill.  You need it to be different on every page load or something?

Comment: Here's a webapp you can use to convert your own images into a base64 representation.  http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64
You could re-implement it in javascript easily enough, but why bother?

Comment: Add my name to the list of people who thinks this is a bad idea. Generating a PNG image is a CPU-intensive task, and should not be done on every page load. It should be done *once* and then saved as a png file (better for page load speed over a slow connection, especially with large images), or embedded with base64 (better for page load speed over a fast connection, especially with small images).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To generate image client-side, I suggest you to have a look to HTML5 canvas element.

You can draw on a canvas with Javascript (even if the canvas element is hidden), and so generate anything you want (including a simple noise tile).

Resource to learn Canvas drawing : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

After that, you can export your canvas as URL with the method toDataURL (a string like "data:image/png;base64....") which is interpreted by browsers like a traditionnal url for an image, so you can set it as css background for your body element.

**Warning 1 :** Canvas is supported by all modern browsers and you can emulate it on IE with [ExplorerCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) - but I don't know if ExplorerCanvas support .toDataURL()

**Warning 2 :** Canvas is resolution-dependant, so I suggest you to generate a little tile (32*32, or 64*64) and repeat it

**Edit :** An example of tiled background : http://jsfiddle.net/SfzPc/12/

**Edit 2 :** An completed example with a noisy background : http://jsfiddle.net/SfzPc/14/

Comment: But how to make visual noise? It's much more difficult than making a perfect circle :)

Comment: Although I do not know yet how to perform the given steps (a little bit of working code would be nice), this is what I was thinking when I asked, generating (and possibly caching) a small square tile. Visual noise generation is a separate, language-independent algorithm, so when I get a good one, I'll implement it using Canvas. Also, I phylosophically sympathize with the Canvas workflow. But that is debatable, of course.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS to display this image:

```css
#someimageselector {
    background: white url('data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...lots of data') repeat scroll left top;
}
```

You can change the initial color of your background by editing the value `white`.

To set CSS with JavaScript, set the `background` property of an element:

```
document.getElementByID("someimageselector").background = 'white url(data:image/png....';
```

Comment: Your answer worked, and I liked the trick. Just one last chance: is it possible/good-practice to algorithmically generate the png data using javascript?

Comment: It is possible, but for users that have JavaScript disabled, you probably should have a backup image. In this particular case, JavaScript isn't needed. It's probably best to generate an image once, and then save it (if possible).

Answer (score 2):

There are two jQuery plugin libraries that do exactly what you are looking for: **NoiseGen** and **Noisy**.  Haven't used either yet but they both look pretty good.

**NoiseGen**

- Project: http://primegap.net/2011/10/20/noisegen-generate-background-noise-with-jquery/
- Demo: http://www.lucaongaro.eu/demos/noisegen/

**Noisy**

- Project: https://github.com/DanielRapp/Noisy
- Demo: http://rappdaniel.com/other/noisy-sample/

Answer (score 1):

Fyi: Base64 is binary data represented as a string.
Most likely the original image still came out of Photoshop and was later encoded into Base64.
This technique helps having less http-requests per page view, as the actual image data can be saved and cached inside the css or html document.