# jQuery: Scramble effect like an old TV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

There's not much to explain, I want to know that there is an effect (made with jQuery and CSS) that when a user scrolls down, there is a chanche that the website scrambles a bit, like a TV with bad connection. I googled it but couldn't find what I was looking for.

EFFECT THAT I WANT TO CREATE:
[image: scrambled effect]

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe you can do it with canvas

Comment: Not really a duplicate question but this SO may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8580845/1045794. Also, this code could be manipulated (@Kermani, with his HTML5 canvas suggestion): http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-effects-app-adding-noise-and-invert/